# Concatenation assignment ".=" for While Loop

Tags: php

Any idea how to use Concatenation assignment .= for While Loop?

```
<?php
$Tag = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Tag .= $row['name'];       
} 
echo $Tag;
```

What I am trying to do is to get echo results something like Tag1 Tag2 Tag3 ...
but instead, I got only the last tag3, not all

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($tag)` and post the output.

Comment: Try declaring the variable before concatenation. `$Tag = '';`

Comment: That looks like it should work. What you're describing really sounds like what would happen if you used `=` instead of `.=`. Are you sure your query is returning all the rows you expect it to? You can try echoing something inside the while loop to check that.

Comment: Declaring the variable before the loop shouldn't make much difference. Without declaring it, you'll get an undefined variable notice the first time the loop executes, but it will still work. [See this example](https://3v4l.org/kZTLs). I haven't downvoted the answers that suggest that, but I really don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Maybe the other rows don't have data in the `name` column? or there is only one row?

Comment: `echo` doesn't give you the full picture of what that variable is. `var_dump()` it and post the output.

Comment: Also, pls post full code sample including query. Your code seems to work OK - http://tpcg.io/hpZDAC

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that $Tag is declared before your while loop. So try using

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

Comment: Using `mysqli_fetch_array` without specifying a fetch style will use the default "both" that will fetch both numeric and string keys.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I know that. That's why I recommended using mysqli_fetch_assoc which doesn't need a fetch style as it always returns an associative array.

Comment: Ah, I thought you might be suggesting this because you thought the way they were doing it might not provide the 'name' key. In that case, how will using the different fetch method fix the problem of only getting a value from the last row?

Comment: Well it's certainly possible that it won't make any difference at all. But there's nothing else that looks wrong with what they have. If my attempt didn't work then the only other logical thing seems to be that the data they're actually returning from the database isn't what they're expecting.